# factors affecting the flavor of cinchona bark

Tags: syrup

For a tonic syrup recipe extracting from cut bark :

Cold brewing or boiling: 
Is it just clarity or are there flavor differences too?

Does metal affect the flavor:
Glass or enamel pan vrs Stainless steel make any difference for steeping or storage?

Any differences steeping with acidic ingredients vrs adding in after filtering?